# Swift #selector in subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After I updated `XCode`, so it can build code for `iOS 9.3` now, I have a lot of warnings about updating the syntax to conform to upcoming `Swift version 3`.

Many warnings are about `Selector`, now I'm using something like this:

```
class Foo {

    func registerPan() {
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePan:"))
        //do something with recognizer
    }

    func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        //handle pan gesture
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {

    override func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        //overriding handle pan gesture
    }
}
```

So instances of `Foo` and `Bar` have their own ways to handle pan gesture. `Xcode` suggests me to change the method I use selectors, to use `#selector expression`. The automatic suggested change by the editor is:

```
#selector(Foo.handlePan(_:))
```

Here comes my question. In the previous version, a specific implementation was called for the base class and for the subclass. Now, it looks like function of `Foo` will be called even for an instance of `Bar` class (`Bar` inherits `registerPan` function from `Foo`). Is this correct?

Probably `XCode` static analysis doesn't care about inheritance here. I'm considering changing these selectors to:

```
#selector(self.handlePan(_:))
```

so an instance of whatever class calls its own implementation, but I want to be sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: Well have you tried it?

Comment: Of course I did. I'm asking what should be done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Apple docs say:

> A selector expression lets you access the selector used to refer to a
>   method in Objective-C.

```
#selector(method name)
```

> The method name must be a reference to a method that is available in
>   the Objective-C runtime. The value of a selector expression is an
>   instance of the Selector type. For example:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {
    @objc(doSomethingWithInt:)
    func doSomething(x: Int) { }
}
let x = SomeClass()
let selector = #selector(x.doSomething(_:))
```

> ..Because the selector is created at compile time, not at runtime, the
>   compiler can check that the method exists and that the method is
>   exposed to the Objective-C runtime.

Also you can make an extension of Selector inside your vc('s) and declare you selectors there:

```
private extension Selector {
    static let updateItems  = #selector(CharactersListVC.updateItems)
    static let getMoreItems = #selector(CharactersListVC.getMoreItems)
}
```

And then just use it this way:

```
button?.addTarget(self, action: .updateItems, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@pkacprzak you are correct just tested this.

## selector(self.handlePan(_:) works fine

//Here is the code

```
class Foo:UIView {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    registerPan()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
func registerPan() {
    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(_:)))
    //do something with recognizer
    self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

@objc func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //handle pan gesture
    print("From Base")
}
}

class Bar: Foo {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
override func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //overriding handle pan gesture
    print("From Child")
}
}
```

here is how it is called...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let bar = Bar(frame: self.view.frame)
  self.view.addSubview(bar)
}
```

Comment: Yes it produces "From Child".

Comment: Not working for me on iOS 10, Xcode 8, Swift 3 - Instead it calls the superclass (ie prints "From Base")